# Did Russia benefit from the Belt and Road Initiative?

Tags: russian-federation, china, belt-and-road-initiative

> This policy has been alleged by the U.S. Government to be a form of
> "Debt-Trap Diplomacy"; however, the term itself has come under
> scrutiny as analysts and researchers have pointed out that there is no
> evidence to prove that China is deliberately aiming to do debt trap
> diplomacy.[92] Research from Deborah Brautigam, an international
> political economy professor at Johns Hopkins University, and Meg
> Rithmire, an associate professor at Harvard Business School, have
> disputed the allegations of Debt Trap Diplomacy by China and pointed
> out that "Chinese banks are willing to restructure the terms of
> existing loans and have never actually seized an asset from any
> country, much less the port of Hambantota". They argued that it was
> 'long overdue' for people to know the truth and not to have it be
> "willfully misunderstood".[93]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belt_and_Road_Initiative

> Unlike many low and middle-income countries that rely on Chinese
> investments and aid for their domestic needs, the bulk of funding to
> Russia supports industries that export to China.
>
> Although Russia has seen a drop in Chinese development funding over
> the years, Moscow will keep courting Beijing, said Ali Wyne, senior
> analyst with Eurasia Group's Global Macro-Geopolitics practice.
>
> "Russia believes that it can advance its great-power pretensions by
> deepening its ties to China, which is the only country that might
> eventually be able to contest the United States for global
> preeminence," Wyne told VOA in a written statement.
>
> Moscow's debt to Beijing totals almost $130 billion, or 7.3% of its
> GDP. However, the lack of grants to Russia speaks to the strength of
> the Russian economy and shows that China expects economic gains by
> investing there, according to AidData.
>
> But Beijing's deepening economic and strategic ties with Russia come
> with a cost, Wyne noted.
>
> "Russia's ongoing aggression against Ukraine has significantly
> undermined China's relationships with the United States and the
> European Union," he said.

https://www.voanews.com/a/countries-in-crisis-top-recipients-of-chinese-funds-/7348919.html

The U.S. says a lot of debt-ridden countries got debt-trapped by China, but I am guessing that Russia because of its oil is not of those countries, but I am wondering if Russia largely benefited from Chinese loans, or whether the picture is not white and black and there were some issues raised by Russia about the benefits of BRI. I am thinking that the interest rate might have been different, the loans might have been structured different and the viability of some of the projects were also different, so I am guessing that BRI wasn't bad for all countries.

Comment: The concept of "benefitting" is ill-defined. Where there are economical gains may be political losses, and vice versa.